# How to send twitter follow request to specific person using tweepy python? [2022]

Tags: python, error-handling, twitter, tweepy, twitter-api-v2

I wrote a code to send follow request to specific users and my logic also seems perfect. Even when I print response.data it shows me my followers' data in a dictionary. But I can't find a way to fetch those names altogether and compare with the specific name of the person I want to follow.

```
import tweepy
import api_keys as ak


def about_me(client: tweepy.Client) -> None:
"""Print information about the client's user."""
# The `public_metrics` addition will give me my followers count, among other things
    me = client.get_me(user_fields=["public_metrics"])
    print(f"My name: {me.data.name}")
    print(f"My handle: @{me.data.username}")
    print(f"My followers count: {me.data.public_metrics['followers_count']}")
    print(f"My User ID: {me.data.id}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
   client = tweepy.Client(
    bearer_token=ak.Bearer_Key,
    consumer_key=ak.API_Key,
    consumer_secret=ak.API_Key_Secret,
    access_token=ak.Access_Token,
    access_token_secret=ak.Access_Token_Secret)
   print("=== About Me ===")

   about_me(client)

for response in tweepy.Paginator(client.get_users_followers, 2351371758, max_results=10, limit=5):
    df = pd.DataFrame(response.data)

print(df)
if df['name'] == 'Leta Disandro':
    response.follow_user()
```

It even stores my requested data into a dataframe but throws error when I try to check for the name in that dataframe. I even tried different variations and these are the errors I encountered:

```
raise ValueError(ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'follow'
AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'follow_user'
```

Answer (score 0):

`df = pd.DataFrame(response.data)` erases `df` at each iteration of the loop.

`if df['name'] == 'Leta Disandro':` is incorrect since you want to check for the `'name'` field of the objects in the dataframe, not from the dataframe object itself.

But do you really need a dataframe anyway?

Finally, `follow_user` is a method of `Client` objects, not of `Response` objects.